In form.io, I want the change of one field to tigger a script in another one
I am working with form.io embedded in en application. But I can't get components of a form to share events. So the form builder is embedded in the admin functions of the application.
I have two fields on my form, a priority dropdown, which is a number, and a due date field.
I want a change of priority to trigger a script under the due date. But it seems that in the logic tab of the due date, I can't select a change event from another component on the form. The instance variable that is available, is only the instance of that component, not the form.
I tried an advanced logic entry, with a custom script, but that didn't seem to be able to see outside it's scope. And the simple trigger only supports a fixed value for another field, not a general change
